# Not able to decrypt in mysql that was encrypted using the php script

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, des

I am encrypting my string using the following php code.

```
$encryption_key = "mickey";
$value = "ddd";
function encrypt($value)
{
    global $encryption_key;
    if(function_exists("mcrypt_ecb"))
    {
        return mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_DES, $encryption_key, $value, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
    }
    else return $value;
}
```

I am storing the encrypted value in the database. This stores "`?P??`" in the database in column "Encrypt"

However when I run this query

```
select DES_DECRYPT(Encrypt,"mickey") from test_encrypt
```

It gives me

```
3f503f1b3f1b20
```

How can I retrieve my original `$value` from the sql query?

Thanks

Comment: mcrypt_ecb has been deprecated as of php 5.5.  Don't think that has anything to do with the issue, just a heads up.

Comment: I'm using php 5.3 and yes, that should't be the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a character set issue to me.

Likely you're storing the binary value into a VARCHAR (or other non-binary type), and a character set conversion is being applied, and some of the bytes aren't valid "characters" in the characterset for the column, either that, or, the stored values are being translated on retrieval, and "unknown" encodings are being replaced with question marks.

As a test, you could try using the MySQL `HEX()` and `UNHEX()` functions on the binary values, though that will effectively double the size of the strings.  There shouldn't be any characterset problem with character strings representing hexadecimal digits. (I don't think there are native base-64 encoding/decoding functions in MySQL.)

Alternatively, you might try storing the encrypted values in a column with a datatype that supports binary data, with no characterset translation, e.g. `VARBINARY` rather than `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights and pointing me to a good direction. I'll try and let you know how it goes.. :)

Comment: Changing datatype from varchar to varbinary worked, although I did not see any binary special characters in the database for the encrypted string